# how to select a specific file from a directory iterator and compare it

Tags: c++

I have two directory iterators that take from the user two input of paths and print their entries name and size.

What I want is to make the user enter a number of index and then the program will take that index's file from both of the directories and compare their size to see if they match each other or not.

The code is this:

```
for (auto& p : recursive_directory_iterator(str1)) {
 ++i;     
cout << "index no. " << i << p.path().filename() << file_size(p.path()) << endl;
} 

for (auto& p : recursive_directory_iterator(str2)) { 
++j;     
cout << "index no. " << j << p.path().filename() <<file_size(p.path()) << endl;    
}
```

I hope what I want is clear. I will appreciate a lot if anyone can help me.

Comment: Are you asking how to get an entry with a specified index from an iterator?

Comment: @interjay  yes, how to get it and compare it size with another entry

Comment: Are there some special criteria to select which entries you want to compare? Filenames, or something else? Or is it the index you yourself count separately from the iterators?

Comment: @DNT yes I want to compare the size of the two entries

Comment: Any two entries? E.g the first of the first set with all of the second, or do you have other requirements?

Comment: @DNT no, there is index of each entry in the loop of my code, I want the user to enter the index of the entry and the program will compare the two entries based on their size

Comment: In that case, you need to store both sets of your entries in `std::vector<std::filesystem::directory_entry>` vectors and then after you obtain user input, `if (file_size(v1[i].path()] > file_size(v2[i].path()]) { ... do something ...}`
Is that what you need?

Comment: @DNT Yes I think It is something like this! But I am very sorry can you write that in the code above? I am not sure if I can make it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for something like this

```
std::vector<std::filesystem::directory_entry> v1, v2;
size_t i;
for (auto& p : std::recursive_directory_iterator(str1))
    v1.push_back(p);
for (auto& p : std::recursive_directory_iterator(str2))
    v2.push_back(p);

std::cin >> i;  // get user input 

if (std::file_size(v1[i].path()] > std::file_size(v2[i].path()]) 
{
   // ... do something ...
}
```

You'll need to add a prompt for the user and also check that the number they entered is `i < v1.size()` and `i < v2.size()`

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you very much. I can't express my thanks enough, really. I hope you have a very nice day.

Comment: You are welcome. You could accept the answer before you go back to your code :)

Comment: Done. Again, Thank you very much.